# Calling JavaScript function from HTML using quick.js

Tags: javascript

I am building a game with [Quick.js](https://github.com/dgsprb/quick/wiki)

The running game can be played [here](http://liesandcowpies.com/quickjs/paddle-index-WIP.html)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--  // programName: BenghaziGame.html here:  http://pastebin.com/jPaFjcWk  
                                .js here: http://pastebin.com/xLcM9G4n
                  Running online:  http://liesandcowpies.com/quickjs/BenghaziGame.html   -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon16.png" />
        <script type='text/javascript' src="quick.js"></script>  
        <style>
            #assets {
                height: 1px;
                overflow: hidden;
                visibility: hidden;
                width: 1px;
            }

            body {
                background-color: Black;
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 0;
            }

            canvas {
                cursor: none;
            }
            table { color: #E1E1E1;
            background-color: #992D2D;
            height: 24px; width: 800px;
            border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>  <!--   html way: <body onresize="bodyResize()">  -->
<div>  
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="10%"> totalScore </td> <td id="totalScore" width="5%"> </td>
    <td width="8%"></td>
    <td width="10%"> oops! </td> <td id="oopsScore" width="5%"> </td>
    <td width="8%"></td>
    <td width="10%"> goodHits </td> <td id="goodHits" width="5%"> </td>
    <td width="8%"></td>
    <td width="10%"> totalShots </td> <td id="totalShots" width="5%"> </td>
  </tr>
   </table>
</div> 
        <div align="center">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
        </div>

        <div id="assets">
            <img id="bgCompound" src="sprites/bgCompound.png" width="320" height="191" />
            <img id="manufacturer" src="sprites/manufacturer.png" width="180" height="100" />
            <img id="restartBtn" src="sprites/RestartButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
            <img id="pauseBtn" src="sprites/PauseButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
            <img id="playBtn" src="sprites/PlayButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
            <img id="quitBtn" src="sprites/QuitButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
            <img id="truth01Sprite" src="sprites/truth01.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="lies01Sprite" src="sprites/lies01.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="truth02Sprite" src="sprites/truth02.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="lies02Sprite" src="sprites/lies02.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="truth03Sprite" src="sprites/truth03.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="lies03Sprite" src="sprites/lies03.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="truth04Sprite" src="sprites/truth04.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="lies04Sprite" src="sprites/lies04.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="sparkSprite" src="sprites/transSpark.png" width="28" height="28" />    
            <img id="pointerSprite" src="sprites/handPointerT.png" width="31" height="36" />
            <img id="throwerSprite" src="sprites/thrower.png" width="64" height="64" />
            <img id="cowpieSprite" src="sprites/cowpie.png" width="32" height="32" />

            <audio id="closeDoor" src="sounds/CloseDoor.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="battleFire" src="sounds/BattleFire.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="oops" src="sounds/oops.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="Hillary-WhatDiff" src="sounds/Splat-Hillary-WhatDiff.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="byebye" src="sounds/GoodByeFemale.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="cymbals" src="sounds/Cymbals.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="pling" src="sounds/Pling.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="pingSound" src="sounds/ping.ogg"></audio>
            <audio id="pongSound" src="sounds/pong.ogg"></audio>
        </div>
<!--    html way:
       <script type='text/javascript'> function bodyResize() {
                // alert('.html  bodyResize from Html. ');
                location.reload(); }
        </script>
            ELSE
        .js way:
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){ location.reload(); } );
</script>      
-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src="BenghaziGame.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
// programName: BenghaziGame.js here:  http://pastebin.com/xLcM9G4n
//                          .html here: http://pastebin.com/jPaFjcWk
// Quick.js here:  http://pastebin.com/Gzqef5fu 
/*  Quick (top dog)
         Point (inherits from Quick)
             Rect (inherits from Point)
                 Sprite (inherits from Rect)
                     GameObject (inherits from Sprite) 
Still: Where does Pointer inherit from ?                     ck  ~paddle-main-NOW.js  for score headings 
*/                   
    "use strict";
     // http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_function 
    var red = 153;
    var green = 45;
    var blue = 45;
    var truth01Trips = 0;   var truth01SVspeed ;  // max trips 6  ,  SaVe speeds
    var truth02Trips = 0;   var truth02SVspeed ;    // max trips 4
    var truth03Trips = 0;   var truth03SVspeed ;    // max trips 7
    var truth04Trips = 0;   var truth04SVspeed ;   // max trips 5
    var lies01STspeed, lies02STspeed, lies03STspeed, lies04STspeed ;  //  STart speeds
    var lies01SVspeed, lies02SVspeed, lies03SVspeed, lies04SVspeed ;  //  save Speeds
    var allPaused = false;
    var compound, manufacturer, thrower;
    var truth01, truth02, truth03, truth04; 
    var lies01, lies02, lies03, lies04; 
    var totalScore = 0; var oopsScore = 0; var goodHits = 0; var totalShots = 0; 
    var buttonsCenter = 0;  
    var Cursor, cursorPoint, cursorPos;     
    var getXx , getYy, countLogs =1;
//  var mousePos = [20,570]; 
    var mousePos1stTimeIn = 1;
    // imports
    var CommandEnum = com.dgsprb.quick.CommandEnum;
    var Quick = com.dgsprb.quick.Quick;
    var GameObject = com.dgsprb.quick.GameObject;
    var Rect = com.dgsprb.quick.Rect;
    var ImageFactory = com.dgsprb.quick.ImageFactory;
    var Scene = com.dgsprb.quick.Scene;
    var Text = com.dgsprb.quick.Text;   
    var Point = com.dgsprb.quick.Point; 

    // static
    function main() {
        Quick.setAutoScale(false);
        Quick.setName("Lies&Cowpies");
        Quick.init(function () { return new FirstScene() });
    }

    var Background = (function () {

        function Background() {
            GameObject.call(this);
            this.setColor("rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")");
            this.setWidth(Quick.getWidth());
            this.setHeight(Quick.getHeight());
        }; 
        Background.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);

        return Background;
    })();

    var PlayBtn = (function () { // PlayBtn class namespace
    function PlayBtn() { // PlayBtn class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("playBtn"); // setImageId, a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of PlayBtn
        // getPointer is a static method of Quick
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(Quick.getCenterX() +10, 570, 100, 30)); // a method of Sprite, to set the boundaries of PlayBtn
        this.setSolid();
        this.setEssential();  // a method of GameObject, sets the PlayBtn object as essential to its Scene,  that if this object expires,  the scene will expire too.  
        this.setBottom(600); this.setLeft(Quick.getCenterX() +10);  this.setTop(572);  // this.setLeft(320);
        buttonsCenter = (Quick.getCenterX() +10);
//      alert('buttonsCenter = ' + buttonsCenter); 
        }   
        PlayBtn.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); 
            return PlayBtn; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();   

    var RestartBtn = (function () { // RestartBtn class namespace
    function RestartBtn() { // RestartBtn class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("restartBtn"); // setImageId, a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of RestartBtn
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(buttonsCenter -250, 570, 100, 30)); // a method of Sprite, to set this boundaries
        this.setSolid();
        this.setEssential();   
        this.setBottom(600); this.setLeft(buttonsCenter -250) ;  this.setTop(572);
        }   
        RestartBtn.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); 
            return RestartBtn; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();   
    var PauseBtn = (function () { // PauseBtn class namespace
    function PauseBtn() { // PauseBtn class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("pauseBtn"); // setImageId, a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of PauseBtn
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(buttonsCenter -125, 570, 100, 30)); // a method of Sprite, to set the boundaries of PauseBtn
        this.setSolid();
        this.setEssential();  // a method of GameObject, sets the PauseBtn object as essential to its Scene,  that if this object expires,  the scene will expire too.  
        this.setBottom(600); this.setLeft(buttonsCenter -125);  this.setTop(572);
        }   
        PauseBtn.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); 
            return PauseBtn; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();   
    var QuitBtn = (function () { // QuitBtn class namespace
    function QuitBtn() { // QuitBtn class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("quitBtn"); // setImageId, a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of QuitBtn
        // getPointer is a static method of Quick
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(buttonsCenter +125, 570, 100, 30)); // a method of Sprite, to set the boundaries of QuitBtn
        this.setSolid();
        this.setEssential();  // a method of GameObject, sets the QuitBtn object as essential to its Scene,  that if this object expires,  the scene will expire too.  
        this.setBottom(600); this.setLeft(buttonsCenter + 125);  this.setTop(572);
        }   
        QuitBtn.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); 
            return QuitBtn; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();   

    var Compound = (function () { // Compound class namespace
    function Compound() { // Compound class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("bgCompound"); // setImageId, a method inherited from Sprite
 //       this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of Compound
        // getPointer is a static method of Quick
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 0, Quick.getWidth(), Quick.getHeight())); // a method of Sprite, to set the boundaries of Compound
        this.setEssential();  // a method of GameObject, sets the Compound object as essential to its Scene,  that if this object expires,  the scene will expire too.  
        this.setBottom(Quick.getHeight() - this.getHeight());
        this.setLeft(0);  this.setTop(378);
        }   
        Compound.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); 
            return Compound; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();   
    var Manufacturer = (function () { // Manufacturer class namespace 
    function Manufacturer() { // Manufacturer class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass 
        this.setImageId("manufacturer"); //setImageId, a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of Manufacturer
        // getPointer is a static method of Quick
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 0, Quick.getWidth(), Quick.getHeight())); // a method of Sprite, to set the boundaries of Manufacturer
        this.setEssential();  // a method of GameObject, sets the Manufacturer object as essential to its Scene,  that if this object expires,  the scene will expire too.  
        this.setBottom(Quick.getHeight() - this.getHeight());
        this.setLeft(618);  this.setTop(468); 
        }   
        Manufacturer.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); // this says the Ball class 
            return Manufacturer; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();   
//
    var Ball = (function () { // Ball class namespace 
    function Ball() { // Ball class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("cowpieSprite"); // setImageId,a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of Ball
        // getPointer is a static method of Quick, whose public members are accessible without creating an instance of that class.
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 0, Quick.getWidth(), Quick.getHeight())); // a method of Sprite, to set the boundaries of Ball
        this.setSolid(); // a method of GameObject , so Ball can collide with other solid objects - correct! 
        this.setBottom(Quick.getHeight() - this.getHeight());
        this.setTop(500);
//      this.controller = Quick.getController();
    }; 
    Ball.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); // this says the Ball class inherits from GameObject
    // override - this comment means the following method overrides (rewrites) the method with the same name defined in the super class (in this case, GameObject)
    Ball.prototype.onCollision = function (gameObject) { // still no instance of Ball here, just class method definition - no instance of this class is created until "new Ball()" is issued
        this.expire() ;  // remove ball from screne to prevent multi hits per initial colllision
        var collision = this.getCollision(gameObject); // get direction at collision 
            if (gameObject.hasTag("truth02")) { // returns true if object contains given tag
                oopsScore ++ ; totalScore = ((goodHits * 3) - (oopsScore * 2));
//              alert('oopsScore = ' + oopsScore);  // check for bad news multi hits
                Quick.play("oops"); // calls a static method from Quick class
            };
        if (gameObject.hasTag("lies02")) { // returns true if object contains given tag
              lies02.setLeft(0); lies02.setVisible(false); lies02.setSpeedX(0);
              truth02.setVisible(true); truth02.setSpeedX(4); 
              goodHits ++ ; totalScore = ((goodHits * 3) - (oopsScore * 2));  // each goodHit = 3 points , each 
              Quick.play('Hillary-WhatDiff'); // calls a static method from Quick class
//            goodHits += 1;  Quick.play("cowMoo"); // calls a static method from Quick class
            };
          updateScores();
    };
                return Ball; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();

    function updateScores () { 
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = totalScore;
        document.getElementById('oopsScore').innerHTML = oopsScore;
        document.getElementById('goodHits').innerHTML = goodHits;
        document.getElementById('totalShots').innerHTML = totalShots;
    }

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
//    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    location.reload();
} );

    var Truth = (function () {
        function Truth() {
            GameObject.call(this);
            this.setImageId("");
            this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 0, Quick.getWidth(), Quick.getHeight()));
//          this.setEssential();
            this.setSolid();
            this.setLeft(0);
            this.setTop(120);
            this.setSpeedX(4);
        }; 
        Truth.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);

        Truth.prototype.offBoundary = function (gameObject) {
           if (this.hasTag("truth02")) { 
                truth02Trips += 1; // increment by 1
                if(truth02Trips > 2) { truth02Trips = 0;
                    truth02.setLeft(0); truth02.setVisible(false); truth02.setSpeedX(0);        
                };
//                Quick.play("oops"); // calls a static method from Quick class
                if(truth02.getVisible() ) { this.bounceX(); // for the horizontal axis 
                this.setImage(ImageFactory.mirror(this.getImage())); // flip image horiz
                };
                if(!truth02.getVisible() ) { 
                lies02.setLeft(0); lies02.setVisible(true); lies02.setSpeedX(4); //  
                };
                };
        };          
        return Truth;
    })();
//  
    var Lies = (function () {

        function Lies() {
            GameObject.call(this);
            this.setImageId("");
            this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 0, Quick.getWidth(), Quick.getHeight()));
//          this.setEssential();
            this.setSolid();
            this.setLeft(0);
            this.setTop(120);
            this.setSpeedX(5);
        }; 
        Lies.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);

        Lies.prototype.offBoundary = function (gameObject) {
            this.bounceX(); // for the horizontal axis 
            this.setImage(ImageFactory.mirror(this.getImage()));
//            alert("Lies.prototype.offBoundary");
        };
        return Lies;

    })();   
//
    var FirstScene = (function () {

        function FirstScene() {
            Scene.call(this);
            this.add(new Background());
            var compound = new Compound();
            this.add(compound);         
            var playBtn = new PlayBtn();
            this.add(playBtn);
            playBtn.addTag("playBtn");
            var restartBtn = new RestartBtn();
            this.add(restartBtn);
            restartBtn.addTag("restartBtn");
            var pauseBtn = new PauseBtn();
            this.add(pauseBtn);
            pauseBtn.addTag("pauseBtn");
            var quitBtn = new QuitBtn();
            this.add(quitBtn);
            quitBtn.addTag("quitBtn");          
            manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
            this.add(manufacturer);         
            var ball = new Ball();
            truth01 = new Truth();
            this.add(truth01);
            truth01.addTag("truth01");
            truth01.setImageId("truth01Sprite"); 
            truth01.setLeft(0);
            truth01.setTop(50);
            truth01.setSpeedX(4);           
            lies01 = new Lies();
            this.add(lies01);
            lies01.addTag("lies01");
            lies01.setImageId("lies01Sprite");
            lies01.setVisible(false);
            lies01.setLeft(0)    //  (-64);
            lies01.setTop(50);
            lies01.setSpeedX(0); 
            truth02 = new Truth();
            this.add(truth02);
            truth02.addTag("truth02");
            truth02.setImageId("truth02Sprite"); 
            truth02.setLeft(0);
            truth02.setTop(120);
            truth02.setSpeedX(6);           
            lies02 = new Lies();
            this.add(lies02);
            lies02.addTag("lies02");
            lies02.setImageId("lies02Sprite");
            lies02.setVisible(false);
            lies02.setLeft(0)    //  (-64);
            lies02.setTop(120);
            lies02.setSpeedX(0); 
            truth03 = new Truth();
            this.add(truth03);
            truth03.addTag("truth03");
            truth03.setImageId("truth03Sprite"); 
            truth03.setLeft(0);
            truth03.setTop(190);
            truth03.setSpeedX(3);           
            lies03 = new Lies();
            this.add(lies03);
            lies03.addTag("lies03");
            lies03.setImageId("lies03Sprite");
            lies03.setVisible(false);
            lies03.setLeft(0)    //  (-64);
            lies03.setTop(190);
            lies03.setSpeedX(0); 
            truth04 = new Truth();
            this.add(truth04);
            truth04.addTag("truth04");
            truth04.setImageId("truth04Sprite"); 
            truth04.setLeft(0);
            truth04.setTop(260);
            truth04.setSpeedX(5);           
            lies04 = new Lies();
            this.add(lies04);
            lies04.addTag("lies04");
            lies04.setImageId("lies04Sprite");
            lies04.setVisible(false);
            lies04.setLeft(0)    //  (-64);
            lies04.setTop(260);
            lies04.setSpeedX(0); 
            thrower = new Thrower();
            this.add(thrower);
            var cursorPoint = new Cursor();
            this.add(cursorPoint);
            var spark = new Spark();
            this.add(spark);
            alert(' Click  anywhere on screen  to activate buttons .');
            Quick.play("battleFire"); // calls a static method from Quick class
        }; 
        FirstScene.prototype = Object.create(Scene.prototype);

        // override
        FirstScene.prototype.getNext = function () {
            return new FirstScene();
        };

        return FirstScene;

    })();
//

    var Cursor = (function () {
        function Cursor() {
            GameObject.call(this);
            this.addTag("pointerSprite");
            this.controller = Quick.getController();
            this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 600, Quick.getWidth(), 30)); // a method of Sprite,set Boundary 
            this.pointer = Quick.getPointer();
            this.setImageId("pointerSprite");
            this.setSolid();
            this.setEssential();            
            this.setBottom(600); this.setLeft(50); this.setTop(572);     
        }; 
        Cursor.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);

        Cursor.prototype.fire = function () {
            var spark = new Spark(); // create a brand new spark to be thrown
            var scene = this.getScene(); // ask for the scene the avatar is 
            scene.add(spark); // add the spark to the same scene I am
            if (spark) {spark.setX(this.getX()) };      
            spark.setSpeedY(10); 
        };

        Cursor.prototype.update = function () {

            if (this.pointer.getPush()) {   // getpush is a method of Pointer as in Mouse pointer
                this.fire(); // call the  Cursor.prototype.fire  method we defined above
                var position = this.pointer.getPosition();
            };
            var mousePos = this.pointer.getPosition();
            this.setPosition(mousePos);
            }
        Cursor.prototype.offBoundary = function (gameObject) {
//          alert('Cursor.prototype.offBoundary');
//          this.setCenterY(587);
        };  
//      this.setCenterY(587);

        return Cursor;
    })();

    var Spark = (function () { // Spark class namespace 
    function Spark() { // Spark class constructor method 
        GameObject.call(this); // call the constructor from the superclass
        this.setImageId("sparkSprite"); // setImageId,a method inherited from Sprite
//        this.pointer = Quick.getPointer(); // pointer is a member property of Spark
        this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 600, Quick.getWidth(), 30)); // a method of Sprite,set
        this.setSolid(); // a method of GameObject , so Spark can collide with other solid objects     
        this.setBottom(600); this.setLeft(50); this.setTop(578);     
        this.controller = Quick.getController();
    }; 
    Spark.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype); 
    Spark.prototype.onCollision = function (gameObject) {         
    var collision = this.getCollision(gameObject); // get direction at collision 

    if (gameObject.hasTag("restartBtn")) { // returns true if object contains given tag
              Quick.play("closeDoor"); // calls a static method from Quick class
               totalScore = 0; oopsScore = 0; goodHits = 0; totalShots = 0;
               updateScores();
            };
          if (gameObject.hasTag("pauseBtn")) { // returns true if object contains given tag
              Quick.play("pling"); // calls a static method from Quick class
              if(!allPaused) {
                truth02SVspeed = truth02.getSpeedX();    truth02.setSpeedX(0);  //              this.setSpeedX(5);
                lies02SVspeed = lies02.getSpeedX();    lies02.setSpeedX(0);  //                     this.setSpeedX(5);
                allPaused = true;
              } 
              else  { alert('You are already paused , try Play  .');
              }
                };
//            };
          if (gameObject.hasTag("playBtn")) { // returns true if object contains given tag
              Quick.play("pling"); // calls a static method from Quick class
              if(allPaused) {
                allPaused = false;  
                truth02.setSpeedX(truth02SVspeed);
                lies02.setSpeedX(lies02SVspeed);
              } 
            };
          if (gameObject.hasTag("quitBtn")) { // returns true if object contains given tag
              Quick.play("byebye"); // calls a static method from Quick class
              window.location = 'https://github.com/dgsprb/quick/wiki';
            };
    };
                return Spark; // finally publishes the class to the outer scope
})();

//
    var Thrower = (function () {
        function Thrower() {
            GameObject.call(this);
            this.addTag("thrower");
            this.controller = Quick.getController();
            this.setBoundary(new Rect(0, 0, Quick.getWidth(), Quick.getHeight()));
            this.pointer = Quick.getPointer();
            this.setImageId("throwerSprite");
            this.setEssential();            
            this.setCenterX(Quick.getWidth() / 2);
            this.setBottom(Quick.getHeight() - this.getHeight());
            this.setTop(506);     
        }; 
        Thrower.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);

        Thrower.prototype.fire = function () {
            var ball = new Ball(); // create a brand new ball to be thrown
            var scene = this.getScene(); // ask for the scene the avatar is 
            scene.add(ball); // add the ball to the same scene I am
            if (ball) {ball.setX(this.getX()) }; // within your Thrower update method       
//                totalShots ++ ;       
            updateScores();
//          if(ball ) { this.ball.setCenterX(this.getCenterX()) } ;
            ball.setSpeedY(-9); 
        };

        Thrower.prototype.update = function () {
            if (this.controller.keyDown(CommandEnum.LEFT) && this.getLeft() > 0) {
                this.moveX(-8);
                }
            if (this.controller.keyDown(CommandEnum.RIGHT) && this.getRight() < Quick.getWidth()) {
                this.moveX(8);
                }               
            if (this.controller.keyPush(CommandEnum.UP) || this.controller.keyPush(CommandEnum.A)) 
               { totalShots += 1;   
                this.fire(); // call the method we defined above
                }
                }
        Thrower.prototype.offBoundary = function (gameObject) {
            this.setCenterX(Quick.getWidth() / 2);
              };                

        return Thrower;
    })();

    main();

})();
```

The Problem: When the browser page changes from/to 'Maximize' to/from 'Restore down' and the scale is off, everything gets magnified.

So I want to reload the page.

I can get the `htmlOnly` method to work:

```
<body onresize="bodyResize()">

<script type='text/javascript'> function bodyResize() {
    // alert('bodyResize from Html. ');
    location.reload(); }
</script>
```

But I really want to use the function within:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="paddle-main-WIP.js"></script>
```

... at line 188:

```
function bodyResize() {
  alert('.js bodyResize 1.');
  location.reload(); 
  alert('.js bodyResize 2.');
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think reloading the page on resize is a very good idea ever. Surely you can recalculate things on the fly to resize things without reloading the entire page.

Comment: Please don't use external code paste services. Instead paste all the relevant code here. And pleaaaase, next time, make the formatting readable and don't mix up code and question-text. I did that for you now  :-)

Comment: I don't think reloading the page on resize is a very good idea ever. Surely you can recalculate things on the fly to resize things without reloading the entire page. – @MattiVirkkunen 
Thanks Matti : 
yes , I agree . I am looking for an alternative solution .

Comment: Please don't use external code paste services. Instead paste all the relevant code here. And pleaaaase, next time, make the formatting readable and don't mix up code and question-text. I did that for you now :-) – @JensWirth 
Thanks Jens :
Do you mean the line numbers ? I didn't know how else to reference code sections .
What is a better way ?

Comment: Could you please fix this and add some brief explanation about why this is the solution or how you got the idea for it? 
This could help understanding others with similar problems. – @JensWirth

[link](http://liesandcowpies.com/quickjs/BenghaziGame.html) Link is fixed .
And line numbers are fixed . 
Btw: What is force a newLine , in markdown ?

Thanks for your help Jens .

Answer (score 0):

Aha! 
Finally , after much more googling I got some answere from these searches:
  trigger browser reload button javascript w3schools 
  capture url address javascript w3schools 
  window.bind resize canvas element example w3schools -jquery -angular
Yielded: 
  .w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp
  .w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp 
Pls excuse abbreviated URLs , I am allowed 1 actual link .

I was able to do it two ways , 1) via .html , 
  and 2) via .js .
.1) .html way: lines 36 and 84 thru 88 . 
      Note:.html way line 36 is commented out . 
.2) .js way ,  lines 36 and 90 thru 93 .
Running game here: http://liesandcowpie...nghaziGame.html
Thanks

```html
1<!DOCTYPE html>
2<!--  // programName: BenghaziGame.html here:  http://pastebin.com/jPaFjcWk  
3                                 .js here: http://pastebin.com/xLcM9G4n
4                   Running online:  http://liesandcowpies.com/quickjs/BenghaziGame.html   -->
5<html>
6 <head>
7  <meta charset="utf-8" />
8  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon16.png" />
9  <script type='text/javascript' src="quick.js"></script>  
10  <style>
11   #assets {
12    height: 1px;
13    overflow: hidden;
14    visibility: hidden;
15    width: 1px;
16   }
17
18   body {
19    background-color: Black;
20    margin: 0;
21    overflow: hidden;
22    padding: 0;
23   }
24
25   canvas {
26    cursor: none;
27   }
28   table { color: #E1E1E1;
29   background-color: #992D2D;
30   height: 24px; width: 800px;
31            border: none; 
32            }
33  </style>
34 </head>
35
36 <body>  <!--   html way: <body onresize="bodyResize()">  -->
37<div> 
38<table align="center">
39  <tr>
40    <td width="10%"> totalScore </td> <td id="totalScore" width="5%"> </td>
41    <td width="8%"></td>
42    <td width="10%"> oops! </td> <td id="oopsScore" width="5%"> </td>
43    <td width="8%"></td>
44    <td width="10%"> goodHits </td> <td id="goodHits" width="5%"> </td>
45    <td width="8%"></td>
46    <td width="10%"> totalShots </td> <td id="totalShots" width="5%"> </td> 
47  </tr>
48   </table>
49</div> 
50  <div align="center">
51   <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
52  </div>
53
54  <div id="assets">
55   <img id="bgCompound" src="sprites/bgCompound.png" width="320" height="191" />
56   <img id="manufacturer" src="sprites/manufacturer.png" width="180" height="100" />
57   <img id="restartBtn" src="sprites/RestartButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
58   <img id="pauseBtn" src="sprites/PauseButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
59   <img id="playBtn" src="sprites/PlayButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
60   <img id="quitBtn" src="sprites/QuitButton.png" width="100" height="25" />
61   <img id="truth01Sprite" src="sprites/truth01.png" width="64" height="64" />
62   <img id="lies01Sprite" src="sprites/lies01.png" width="64" height="64" />
63   <img id="truth02Sprite" src="sprites/truth02.png" width="64" height="64" />
64   <img id="lies02Sprite" src="sprites/lies02.png" width="64" height="64" />
65   <img id="truth03Sprite" src="sprites/truth03.png" width="64" height="64" />
66   <img id="lies03Sprite" src="sprites/lies03.png" width="64" height="64" />
67   <img id="truth04Sprite" src="sprites/truth04.png" width="64" height="64" />
68   <img id="lies04Sprite" src="sprites/lies04.png" width="64" height="64" />
69    <img id="sparkSprite" src="sprites/transSpark.png" width="28" height="28" />    
70   <img id="pointerSprite" src="sprites/handPointerT.png" width="31" height="36" />
71   <img id="throwerSprite" src="sprites/thrower.png" width="64" height="64" />
72   <img id="cowpieSprite" src="sprites/cowpie.png" width="32" height="32" />
73
74   <audio id="closeDoor" src="sounds/CloseDoor.ogg"></audio>
75   <audio id="battleFire" src="sounds/BattleFire.ogg"></audio>
76   <audio id="oops" src="sounds/oops.ogg"></audio>
77   <audio id="Hillary-WhatDiff" src="sounds/Splat-Hillary-WhatDiff.ogg"></audio> 
78   <audio id="byebye" src="sounds/GoodByeFemale.ogg"></audio>
79   <audio id="cymbals" src="sounds/Cymbals.ogg"></audio>
80   <audio id="pling" src="sounds/Pling.ogg"></audio>
81   <audio id="pingSound" src="sounds/ping.ogg"></audio>
82   <audio id="pongSound" src="sounds/pong.ogg"></audio>
83  </div>
84<!-- html way: 
85        <script type='text/javascript'> function bodyResize() {
86             // alert('.html  bodyResize from Html. ');
87          location.reload(); }
88  </script>
89      ELSE 
90  .js way:
91<script type="text/javascript" >
92window.addEventListener("resize", function(){ location.reload(); } );
93</script>  
94-->
95  <script type='text/javascript' src="BenghaziGame.js"></script>
96  
97  
98 </body>
99</html>
100
```

Comment: Your URL is not working. The "html way" lines 90-93 says "js way" in the code example. The "js way" line 84-88 says "html way" in the code example. Could you please fix this and add some brief explanation about why this is the solution or how you got the idea for it? This could help understanding others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

What if you comment out / remove this line from your code:

```
Quick.setAutoScale(false);
```

And just let Quick do the automatic scaling for you? If you must, you could also call:

```
Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
```

To make it keep the game aspect instead of stretching.

Reference: [Quick API](https://github.com/dgsprb/quick/wiki/API#quick)

Comment: Hmm... I just added 'add another answer' , but I can't find it now . Anyways ,   I think you are refering to my other Post here: 
**stackoverflow.com/questions/36105157/how-to-trigger-quick-setautoscalefalse-multitimes-with-quick-js**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Diogo ,

I think you are refering to my other Post here: 
stackoverflow.com/questions/36105157/how-to-trigger-quick-setautoscalefalse-multitimes-with-quick-js

But I will answer it here (and Post stuff below there also.):

"@DiogoSchneider: And just let Quick do the automatic scaling for you? " 
I tried that initially , but that enlarged icons to 78x78 .
That's what led me to  Quick.setAutoScale(false); .

Normal screen Canvas should be 800x600 .

While still keeping 'window.addEventListener("resize", function(){'  IN PLAY: 
If I run with
    //  Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    //  Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
Screen is magnified (canvas = ?x? , can't tell because when I switch to debug screen , it changes every thing) 
and icons are 132x78 , for both 'restore down' and 'maximize' .

When I run with 
    function main() {
    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
    Quick.setName("Lies&Cowpies");
    Quick.init(function () { return new FirstScene() });

All is well in 'restore down' and 'maximize' canvas = 800x600 , icons = 64x64 . 
Except that , because of 'reload' I loose all scores etc..

If I run with 'window.addEventListener("resize", function(){'  NOT IN PLAY , and 
    function main() {
    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
    Quick.setName("Lies&Cowpies");
    Quick.init(function () { return new FirstScene() });

In 'restore down' mode , screen is normal  canvas = 800x600 , icons = 64x64 . 
In 'maximize' mode ,  screen is magnified (canvas = 956x~713)  and icons are 78x78 .

Result: I still need 'window.addEventListener("resize", function()' to reset things properly .

As a last resort , 
I also tried 
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    //    location.reload();
    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
    } );

'restore down' canvas = 830x~633  , icons = 64x64 .
'maximize' canvas = 955x724   icons = 78x78

Result: I still need 'window.addEventListener("resize", function()' to reset things properly .

Comment: I'll second @MattiVirkkunen that reloading things on every resize is probably not the best approach. I also peeked the other question. I'd rather let Quick do the heavy work of automatically scaling things around. If you're not pleased with some particular ratio you can always fine tune your canvas size. But the beauty of Virtual Resolution is exactly not caring about that at all.

Comment: Hi Diogo , 
Pls , reread my Question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105157/how-to-trigger-quick-setautoscalefalse-multitimes-with-quick-js 
You'll see that I tried 'Virtual Resolution' first , but it didn't work . 
So I tried several other things , which didn't work either .
I still need an answer . Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean. You have other HTML elements beyond the canvas area. Quick's autoscale won't work with that indeed. It was intended for games which try to take advantage of a "full screen" approach. So my other recommendation for you is trying to do something similar to what Quick does instead, but adjusted to your particular needs. Please see how Quick implements the autoscale feature: https://github.com/dgsprb/quick/blob/master/src/quick.js#L296

You could implement a similar function to be called upon the "resize" event, just different, adding more room for your other elements.