# How to trigger 'Quick.setAutoScale(false)' multiTimes with Quick.js

Tags: javascript

Currently I am using the `location.reload();` from `addEventListener("resize")`  to reset AutoScale, whenever 'Maximize' or 'Restore Down' is clicked . But when I do this, all my scores are lost. Without `location.reload()` `setAutoScale` gets set to `true`.
How can I `Quick.setAutoScale(false);` without reloading the page?

A copy of my game [is here](http://liesandcowpies.com/quickjs/BenghaziGame.html), and below are details for things I have tried and the effects they've had.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
//    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    location.reload();
//  Quick.setAutoScale(false);
//  Quick.init(function () { return new FirstScene() });
} );
```

If I comment out `Quick.setAutoScale(false)`, the icons get enlarged to 78x78, which is why I added `Quick.setAutoScale(false)`. Normal screen Canvas should be 800x600 .

While still keeping `window.addEventListener("resize", function()`, if I run the following:

```js
    //  Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    //  Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
```

Screen is magnified (canvas = ?x?, I can't tell because when I switch to debug screen, it changes everything) and icons are 132x78 , for both 'restore down' and 'maximize'.

When I run with

```js
    function main() {
    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
    Quick.setName("Lies&Cowpies");
    Quick.init(function () { return new FirstScene() });
```

All is well in 'restore down' and 'maximize' canvas = 800x600 , icons = 64x64 . 
Except that because of 'reload' I lose all scores etc.

If I don't use `window.addEventListener("resize", function()`

```js
    function main() {
    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
    Quick.setName("Lies&Cowpies");
    Quick.init(function () { return new FirstScene() });
```

In 'restore down' mode, screen is normal canvas = 800x600, icons = 64x64 . 
In 'maximize' mode, screen is magnified (canvas = 956x~713)  and icons are 78x78.

As a last resort, I also tried:

```js
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    //    location.reload();
    Quick.setAutoScale(false);
    Quick.setKeepAspect(true);
    } );
```

'restore down' canvas = 830x~633, icons = 64x64 and 'maximize' canvas = 955x724  icons = 78x78

Result: I still need `window.addEventListener("resize", function()` to reset things properly.

Comment: I put tags (javascript & static-libraries) . I am not sure if Quick.js is a static-library or not . But I wanted more than just javascript . Any chance of adding  'Quick.js' to allowable tags ? Thanks

Comment: I've [formatted your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36105157/3) to hopefully be a little clearer. It appears the question you are actually asking though is ***How can I prevent the page from scaling things when it reloads, whilst keeping the things I want the same size.*** Is that correct? If so, it might be worth clarifying, because otherwise it might be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)